# Extreme value from every type in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have SQL table with id_item, type, hour, minutes, id_client.
I would like to display one record from each type, which was bought recently.
I mean one record from each type where hour is the highest -> if equal, then where minutes value is the highest.
Is it possible? I tried some queries, but I can't figure out how to do this.
I did this one:

```
SELECT type, MAX(hour) FROM shop AS a GROUP BY type ORDER BY type
INNER JOIN (SELECT type, hour, minutes, id_client FROM shop AS b) ON a.type = b.type AND a.hour=b.hour
```

But there's an error "syntax error at or near "INNER".
It also doesn't include checking minutes when hour is the same.

Comment: The INNER JOIN part should be in the FROM clause, i.e. before the GROUP BY etc. (Alternatively, do the GROUP BY part in a separate subquery.)

Comment: Dziękuję! To mi wiele rozjaśniło i udało się zrobić :)

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to display one record from each type, which was bought recently.

This suggests window functions:

```
select s.*
from (select s.*,
             row_number() over (partition by type order by hour desc, minutes desc) as seqnum
      from shop s
     ) s
where seqnum = 1;
```

Note:  It seems quite strange that you are only storing hours and minutes instead of a full timestamp to represent time.